# Connecting to a runtime to enable file browsing(colab.research.google.com/drive/...)

Tags: google-colaboratory

While working with the environment

```
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/....
```

I face this all the time

```
Connecting to a runtime to enable file browsing
```

Interestingly, three days ago, everything was fine and there were no problems. From today, everything I try is useless